# Error in success callback: NetworkStatus0 = TypeError

Tags: cordova, sencha-touch, extjs, sencha-touch-2

I am getting the following error, What does it mean, and how can i solve it.Everything seems OK to me, i went line by line but couldn't find anything unusual in the code.

> [INFO] Error in success callback: NetworkStatus0 = TypeError: Result
>   of expression '(userAgent, navigation.platform)' [iPhone] is not a
>   constructor.

I have included my code below, please have a look. Tell me how to get rid of this error;

```
Ext.setup({
          onReady: function() {
          console.log('application launched Ready OK');
          var form;
          //form and related fields config
          var formBase = {
          //enable vertical scrolling in case the form exceeds the
          //page height
          scroll: 'vertical',
          url: 'http://97.74.206.195/web_service/',
          items: [{//add a fieldset
                  xtype: 'fieldset',
                  title: 'Personal Info',
                  instructions: 'Please enter the information above.',
                  //apply the common settings to all the child items
                  // ￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼Getting your form ready with FormPanel
                  //￼￼  of the fieldset
                  defaults: {
                  required: true,
                  labelAlign: 'left',
                  labelWidth: '40%'
                  }, items: [
                             //required field
                             {//add a text field
                             xtype: 'textfield',
                             name : 'name',
                             label: 'Name',
                             useClearIcon: true,//shows the clear icon in the
                             //field when user types
                             autoCapitalize : false
                             }, {//add a password field
                             xtype: 'passwordfield',
                             name : 'password',
                             label: 'Password',
                             useClearIcon: false
                             }, {
                             xtype: 'passwordfield',
                             name : 'reenter',
                             label: 'Re-enter Password',
                             useClearIcon: true
                             }, {//add an email field
                             xtype: 'emailfield',
                             name : 'email',
                             label: 'Email',
                             placeHolder: 'you@sencha.com',
                             useClearIcon: true
                             }] }
                  ],
          listeners : {
          //listener if the form is submitted, successfully
          submit : function(form, result){
          console.log('success', Ext.toArray(arguments));
          },
          //listener if the form submission fails
          exception : function(form, result){
          console.log('failure', Ext.toArray(arguments));
          }
          },
          //items docked to the bottom of the form
          dockedItems: [
                        {
                        xtype: 'toolbar',
                        dock: 'bottom',
                        items: [
                                {
                                text: 'Reset',
                                handler: function() {
                                form.reset();  //reset the fields
                                }
                                }
                                ]
                        } ]
          };

          // Check for device
          var navigation = Ext.global.navigator,
          userAgent = navigation.userAgent,
          osEnv, osName, deviceType;

          Ext.os = osEnv = new this(userAgent, navigation.platform);

          osName = osEnv.name;

          var search = window.location.search.match(/deviceType=(Tablet|Phone)/),
          nativeDeviceType = window.deviceType;


          if (search && search[1]) {
          deviceType = search[1];
          console.log('application launched Ready OK1');

          }
          else if (nativeDeviceType === 'iPhone') {
          console.log('application launched Ready OK2');

          formBase.fullscreen = true;
          } else { //if desktop
          Ext.apply(formBase, {
                    autoRender: true,
                    floating: true,
                    modal: true,
                    centered: true,
                    hideOnMaskTap: false,
                    height: 385,
                    width: 480
                    });
          }
          //create form panel
          form = new Ext.form.FormPanel(formBase);
          form.show();  //render the form to the body
          console.log('application launched Ready OK3');

          }
          });
```